# Validation of certificate in WCF Client written in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, ssl, client

I have very simple test client WCF Service. WCF Service is protected by user and password and ssl.

My test client looks like this:

```
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
            delegate
            {
                return true;
            });

        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(@"https://localhost:8083/WS/Service.svc");

        using (var service = new ServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress))
        {
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"user";
            service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"password";

            var data = service.GetData();
        }
```

Is it possible to remove line:

```
       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
            delegate
            {
                return true;
            });
```

Whenever I remove this line I got **SecurityNegotiationException**.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the parameters instead of returning true. They will tell you, why your client thinks the certificate is not valid.

Comment: Details: "You can not establish a trust relationship for the secure channel SSL / TLS"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have ignored all useful information given to you on purpose. The callback you used should give you all information you need:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        delegate(
        Object obj,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            // instead of the shortcut "true" here, evaluate the parameters!
            return true;
        };
```

Make sure you find out what the `errors` are and fix them in your system.

Comment: The error is RemoteCertificateNameMismatch. Can you please tell how to solve it? Do I have to define certificate with the same name like server name?

Comment: @ijon yes, that would help. You should read more on SSL/TLS certificates in general. That's too broad to handle here.

Comment: can you share a link with a good description? I got stuck because I don't know how to name self-signed certificate.